# Powershell - Can't figure out how to get web content from IE object

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am pretty new to **Powershell** and just using it for personal stuff. I have been experimenting with pulling specific info from websites to include in emails to family.  By reading the forums I got pretty good using the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet, but soon hit upon its limitation of not having access to content constructed dynamically at the time the page is loaded.

Thanks to these forums, I then discovered the IE object and how to pull the data.  I had luck with one website, but another I tried does not work the same.  Hoping for a little help figuring it out.

Here is a snippet of the inspected code for the page, with my target of interest highlighted.

[image: Web Page Snippet]

Below is the code where I am trying to extract that text string.  I have tried many iterations and approaches with no success.  What is odd, though, the `$ie.Document` object supposedly has a "body" object, but when I tried to access it, I get a null object error.  I notice the Document object itself has a `getElementsByTagName` method, so I tried that.  It does not have a `getElementsByClassName` method.

Note that the URL I am loading is "https" so I am wondering if this is causing issues.  Suggestions appreciated!  If I can just get a surrounding chunk of the HTML, I am fine doing some string manipulation to get what I want.

```html
#  Create IE object and load URL

$WeatherURL = "https://weather.com/weather/today/l/77630"
$ie = New-Object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($WeatherURL)

 # Wait for the page to load 

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true -Or $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {Start-Sleep 2}

$Doc = $ie.Document

$Weather0 = $Doc.getElementsByTagName('span') `
 | ?{$_.getAttribute('class') -eq "today-wx-descrip"} | Select-Object -First 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
$Weather0 = $Doc.getElementsByTagName('span') `
| ?{$_.getAttribute('class') -eq "today-wx-description"} | Select-Object -First 1
```

With

```
$Weather0 = $Doc.getElementsByTagName('span') `
| ?{$_.getAttribute('class') -eq "today-wx-descrip"} | Select-Object -First 1
```

Note **today-wx-description** vs **today-wx-descrip**.

Comment: Oops, you are right, but in one of my iterations while hacking this I fixed that.  I have replaced the code snippet in the OP.  When this runs, I get an insufficient memory error.